# T-SQL wildcard not operator ^ not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

T-SQL Not wildcard:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE City LIKE 'A[^a]%';
```

It returns: 'Aachen'

So what is the meaning of ^ operator here, same result will come if use

```
WHERE City LIKE 'A[a]%';
```

I know I can use `'A[!a]%'` and will work, my concern is then why `^`?

Comment: if it is not anything like that in sql then it should give error, strange :) see the MSDN link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Comment: It's working fine on my database (SQL Server 2014)

Comment: Why should it give an error? Maybe you _are_ looking for the character `^`

Comment: If ! is working then you have a strange configuration as ^ in [ ] is not.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Comment: Works for me. Try: Select 'match' where 'Aachen' LIKE 'A[^a]%';

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://zarez.net/?p=1549):

> **The Caret Wildcard Character [^]:**
>
> The Caret Wildcard Character is used to search for any single
>   character not within the specified range [^a-c] or set [^abc].
>
> To find all employees with a 3 characters long first name that begins
>   with ‘Ja’ and the third character is not ‘n’:
>
> ```
> SELECT FirstName, MiddleName, LastName
> FROM Person.Person
> WHERE FirstName LIKE 'Ja[^n]'
> ```
>
> [image]

Here is a screenshot depicting that it is working as expected:

[image]

Comment: Can you just run your query and check the result, it is not working.

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi: How does that answer the question? Why is 'Aachen' retrieved when the pattern is `LIKE 'A[^a]%'` which should exclude cities with an 'a' after the initial 'A'?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner:- It is working as expected. I just verified it on my SQL Server and attached the screen shot of the same.

Comment: @AliAdravi:- It is working as expected. I executed the same on my SQL Server and it is working. Are you sure you tried with the same query?

Comment: What version of SQL server you are using, on 2008 it is not working

Comment: @AliAdravi:- I am using SQL Server 2008 R2